# Workflow visualization without using Visio Services

Tags: workflow, visio-services

I need to implement visualization of declarative workflows on SharePoint 2010 standart edition. I know that it can be done by using of Visio Services. But it is part of enterprise edition.
Is there a way to implement visualization of declarative workflows without Visio Services? Can somebody advise some existing solution or explain how it can be implemented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found appropriate solution which works for declarative workflows. This task can be spitted in three subtasks:

1)Retrieving information about workflow structure;

2)Retrieving information about activities details;

3)Building of the visual representation.

The markup of declarative workflows is described by XOML file. The XOML files are located in library. The ID of the library, item’s ID and version of the file can be retrieved from *CodeBesideAssembly* element of the workflow template XML. Using this information workflow’s XOML file can be retrieved.

Activities details can be retrieved using *GetActivityDetails* method of *SPWorklfow* object. But this method works only for workflows for which *ShowPreview* property is set to true in workflow configuration file.

Workflow markup and information about activities can be used to build visual representation of workflow. There are a lot of ways to do it. For example it is possible to use custom Silverlight control or JavaScript application.

Answer (score 1):

Existing solution are (for example) thrid party workflow tools like K2 Blackpoint/Blackpearl and Nintex Workflow 2010.

[image: Nintex Workflow Visualization (by vadim tabakman)]

Answer (score 0):

I have seen some folks use graphics that show the workflow process, this is mainly for the benefit of end users to see where something is at in the process.  The graphics would highlight the current step and give users a sense of what is coming in the process and what has been completed.

If you don't have enterprise or a third party workflow solution, it might be your best option.

Comment: Can you provide an example or explain more detailed how such graphics can be implemented.

Comment: I'll have to look for it, I recall it being in a DVWP demonstration video from Laura Rogers a few years ago.